# Corporate Portal for Managers/Executives

Tags: ecm

We are looking into a Managers' portal for our organization. This site will host hot topics, accumulated knowledge about leadership related issues, links to relevant management site etc.

I was wondering whether any of you had experience with a portal of this specific type or can point me to articles/case studies related to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Book**

[Microsoft SharePoint 2010: Creating and Implementing Real-World Projects](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=V3RsmLOEa8kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=real%20life%20sharepoint&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PTFlUfKeMse60QXrxoGwDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=real%20life%20sharepoint&f=false)

**Chapter 1**

[Building a Project Management Solution](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=V3RsmLOEa8kC&printsec=frontcover&dq=real%20life%20sharepoint&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PTFlUfKeMse60QXrxoGwDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=real%20life%20sharepoint&f=false)

I am pretty sure solution in book will give you a over sight of how solution will be like if not then atleast it will show you how to design solution you want e.g. steps involved.

Comment: Thanks! This is an excellent resource in general. I can actually use it for our learning site  (I saw there was a corresponding chapter). If anyone has experience /case studies about designing sites that are designated to managers ( not necessarily project managers - those sites are project oriented and not management oriented ) , it can be great. Thanks again.